# Set Arlo Mode with SmartThings

Tags: security, samsung-smartthings, digital-cameras, mobile-applications

If it's possible, how can I set the "Mode" for an Arlo device using a SmartThings Routine? Ideally, I would simply set the camera modes when SmartThings goes into various security modes.

I've found that I don't really like the Arlo security modes and have created my own notification/recording modes and set them to a schedule in the Arlo app. But I'd prefer it to be triggered by our family's presence like with SmartThings.

Looking into SmartThings Routines, it appears that I can "turn on" the camera in a routine, but I'm not quite sure what that means. There doesn't appear to be an option to record video through SmartThings except when viewing the device.

**Update**:

[This SmartThings post](https://community.smartthings.com/t/question-about-new-arlo-integration/56048/14) helped quite a bit in how to integrate Arlo into routines. hirsti's Step by Step instructions help the most (it didn't seem to have an anchor...)

See my answer below for steps

Comment: Some links to documentation would help this question (I think). Reading the question, it's hard to understand all of the context (unless someone is very familiar with these specific devices).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is said in [netgear pages](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Arlo-Knowledge-Base/What-is-Samsung-SmartThings-and-how-do-I-use-it-with-my-Arlo/ta-p/1131587) that:

> After you integrate your Arlo cameras into the SmartThings app, you must use the SmartThings app to configure your modes and rules. If you edit your modes and rules in the Arlo app, you disarm the SmartThings mode.

So, custom Modes and all logics should be on Smartthings side.

Answer (score 3):

This ended up working for me:

- Create a new mode in Arlo app. Have it do any recording or notifications
- Connect Arlo to SmartThings (using Arlo Connect SmartApp)
- Add each Arlo device as needed
- Select each newly added Arlo device and set it to Inactive (click the green camera icon from status screen of Thing)
- As needed, update Smart Home Monitor routines (ie Good Morning!, Good Night!, Goodbye!, and I'm Back!) to turn off/on the cameras as switches

By turning off/on the camera as a switch in SmartThings, it is essentially the same as turning off/on the **Camera** switch when configuring camera settings through the Arlo app.

Configuring SmartThings/Arlo Camera Status (only needs to be done in SmartThings)
[image: SmartThings Camera Status][image: Arlo camera configuration]

Configuring automation routines. Activating in SmartThings, tasks are handled in Arlo mode:
[image: Setting the Smart Home Monitor routine in SmartThings][image: Setting the Arlo mode to SmartThings for recording]